# Are we limited to US patents?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this site only and specifically for the USA patent system?](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-this-site-only-and-specifically-for-the-usa-patent-system)

Are the questions here limited to the US patent system? Can I ask questions about the UK patent system? Can I ask questions about foreign patents being applied in the UK?

For example, can I ask "Is it true US software patents can be applied in the UK?"

Comment: Hopefully you find your answer in this duplicate discussion listed above. Feel free to add your own answer *there* so we do not split this discuss between two different threads.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Good call. Missed that.